# Is it possible to preserve long lines in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

My restructuredText input file to Sphinx has a long line:

```
This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It should not be wrapped in the text output.
```

Using the text builder of Sphinx, I get this output:

```
This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It
should not be wrapped in the text output.
```

Sphinx wraps the line. 
I would like to keep the single long line as is. Is this possible?

---

Using [Line Blocks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) was suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033646/5771861). However using line blocks changes the indentation of the line. I could not find a way to keep the indentation same with Line Blocks.

For input:

```
Prev Line

| This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It should not be wrapped in the text output.

Next Line
```

I get this output:

```
Prev Line

   This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It should not be wrapped in the text output.

Next Line
```

The long line is kept long but it is indented now.

---

I was not able to find a setting about line wrapping in Sphinx configuration [page](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration).

---

I am using sphinx-build version 1.7.4 and the command I use is:

```
 sphinx-build -M text "." "_build"
```

---

Update:

The code-block [directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html#directive-code-block) also indents the long line.

Input:

```
Prev Line

.. code-block:: text

  This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It should not be wrapped in the text output.

Next Line
```

Output:

```
Prev Line

   This is a long line text that I want to keep as a long single line. It should not be wrapped in the text output.

Next Line
```

Comment: Perhaps `.. code-block:: text` preceding the long line, with the long line indented? I'm unsure how it will render in text output, but it works well for HTML output.

Comment: @StevePiercy Tried the `code-block` directive. It still indents the long line in the text output. Updated my question with an example. FYI.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The white-space you see is a result of CSS, not actual indentation with space characters. You can use a custom CSS file to override your theme that removes left- and right-padding from the `<pre>` tag. See a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501239/2214933

Comment: @StevePiercy I am using the [text builder](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/builders.html#sphinx.builders.text.TextBuilder) of Sphinx. The output is not html but a raw text file. In that case, are the css files used ?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I missed that you were using the text builder. I don't know if there is a way to do what you want. I'd suggest asking through Sphinx's support channels.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patching the rendering of line blocks for Text writer works for me:

add this to conf.py

```
def my_visit_line_block(self, node):
    # type: (nodes.Node) -> None
    self.new_state(indent=0)
    self.lineblocklevel += 1

def setup(app):
    from sphinx.writers.text import TextTranslator
    TextTranslator.visit_line_block = my_visit_line_block
```

The obvious defect is that it modifies rendering of all line blocks...

I am not familiar enough about [sphinx.writers.text](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/1.7/sphinx/writers/text.py) (and docutils) to see immediately if there is better way than the above monkey-patching.

I could re-insert indentation via this mark-up:

```
| \    one
| \    two
| \    three
```

but being forced to modify mark-up is bad.